# Should I restructure my question if I was looking in the wrong place?

Tags: discussion

For example, I might pose a problem and tag it with PHP and Laravel, and provide settings and information about these two things.

Then, during the course of digging deeper, I find the real problem is Docker.

Should I go back and edit the question?  Should I remove the unnecessary tags and add the correct tags?  Should I remove the unnecessary settings and information, and add details for the real problem?

Comment: As long as the question hasn't received any answers you are free to make major changes like this. If it already has answers only edits that don't invalidate those answers are acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, Luuklag, I think that's the same thing you said. "As long as it doesn't invalidate existing answers"

Comment: There's one other thing besides answers that I'd keep in mind: votes. If there are a lot of positive votes on a question already, changing it to something else would also invalidate all those existing votes, and might be frowned upon by some people, resulting in pushback. You could consider a self-answer if more people found the question useful. For downvotes, perhaps a clean slate might be nice. Either way, self-deleting and posting a new question may be an option too under certain circumstances.